# Ebay rest api not working for my sandbox account

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm using sandbox and i have generated 
Key and token

I have my seller sandbox account .

I'm trying to use sell api (inventory and fullfillment ),but its giving as "A resource (URI) associated with the request could not be resolved" with an error code 3003.

This is the git hub package i'm using in my code .

```
 <?php
     // Your  token
 $authToken = 'AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**MJNfXQ**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';

 $header = array('Accept: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken,
   'Content-Type: application/json'
    ); 
 $placeOrderUrl = 
  "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v2/order/110181400870- 
  27973775001";

 $body = '{}';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($placeOrderUrl));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$body);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 $information = curl_getinfo($ch);
 print_r($response);

 ?>
```

I needs to pull the orders as in the doc for the rest api . 
I don't know where i'm stuck . Thanks in advance if any one can help me out .

Comment: Can you add to the question your code to show what you are doing.  At the moment it's difficult to be able to help.

Comment: How did you get the `authToken` ?

Comment: @CalebGoodman There is an option to generate token without application option.

Comment: The `authToken` looks to me like a `refreshToken`, and not what you are supposed to use in the `Authorization` header.  Can you update your question with exactly how you got this token?

Comment: Also, the ebay sandbox is notoriously inconsistent, and I personally can't get my sandbox credentials to work.  You might be better off testing with production credentials.